# Custom sort with insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting

I've gotten the basics of insertion code but I'm stuck on how to compare it with another condition other then (list by A-Z, Z-A)

for the example a list of staff ranks were given :

```
public static final String[] staffrank = {
        "Trainee",
        "Junior",
        "Senior",
        "Administrator"
    };
```

I have a method to compareRank

If it returns 0 means they're of equal rank (staff 1 and staff 2)

if it returns -1 means staff 1 is lower rank than staff 2

if it returns 1 means staff 1 is higher rank than staff 2

Then I have a list of staffs in void main

```
Staff[] snames;
    int countname=0;
    snames = new Staff[50];
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Amy","Trainee");
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Annie","Junior");
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Tom","Administrator");
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Dave","Trainee");
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Gary","Junior");
    snames[countname++] = new Staff("Donna","Senior");
```

then the insertion sort compare code

```
public static void insertionSortbyRank(Staff[] snames, int countname) {


//insertion sort
for(int i =1; i < countname; i++) {
int j = i;
int comparerank = Staff.compareRank(snames[j],snames[j-1]);

String name = snames.getName();
String rank = snames.getRank();

//if staff is lower rank
if(comparerank==-1) {
```

Then i'm unsure what to put in this while loop
still giving me an unsorted list

```
while( j >0 && rank.compareRank(list[j], list[j - 1]) == 1))) {
   list[j].rank =[j-1].rank;
   list.[j].name = [j-1].name;

   j--;
}
```

then the end is replacing the new values

```
snames[j].name = name;
snames[j].rank = rank;
```

the output suppose to give : (by order of their ranks from low to highest according to the chart)

Amy, Trainee 
Dave, Trainee 
Annie, Junior 
Gary, Junior 
Donna, Senior 
Tom, Administrator

Any help would be appreciated..thank you

Comment: It's tagged "homework" so I assume it is.. :)

Comment: it was one of my exam questions..
but we won't know the answer since it was the finals.
i didn't even tag homework... it was the guy who "edited" my post

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that since you've been given a `staffrank` variable, that you should probably make use of it.  However, aside from mentioning it at the top of your question, you make no other use of it that we've been shown...So my assumption is that you've ignored it completely.

I think that's the key to your puzzle here.

Note that I'm ignoring the fact that String arrays are not the best representation (I'd go for an `enum` or something like a class...Potentially implementing `Comparable<StaffRank>` somewhere...But this is a test question as noted, after all...)

Comment: sadly we weren't allowed to add any class of our own. we can only use the class already provided to us.

All we had was a list of the "custom" sort order, and the list of items to get sorted, along with those empty methods to fill up ourselves.

Comment: I understand that.  That's why I started off by pointing out the `staffrank` String array, and couched the notes about using an `enum` or a Comparable class as an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function like this:

```
public static final int compareRank(String[] ranks, String rank) {
    for (int i=0; i<ranks.length; i++) {
        String string = ranks[i];
        if string.equals(rank) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Which will return an integer between -1 and (ranks.length -1) which you can use for comparison. The smaller the number the more junior the rank.

Inside your while loop you'll have to compare each staff and swap them if the "i"-th staff is greater than the "i+1"-th staff.

```
for (int i=0; i<(snames.length-1); i++) {
    Staff sname1 = sname[i];
    Staff sname2 = sname[i+1]
    //compare sname1 to sname2 and swap if sname1 > sname2
}
```